# Spotify apps tabs - update cache

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to display a div inside tab playlists if the href contains a spotifyURI. This will be used to display a playlist under a tab.

Step by step this is my problem:

1. Click playlist tab and then click the "My playlist1".
2. The href is displayed in the playlist container under the tab playlists. (perfect so far)
3. Click the start tab and then click the playlists tab.
4. Instead of displaying the list of playlists the playlist container is show again. So the last used url is cached?
5. Then if the playlists tab is clicked again the url will be "reseted" and the list of playlists will be shown and playlist container hidden.

I'd like 4. to show the playlist list right away instead. 
Is there a way to reset or what am I missing?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    sp = getSpotifyApi(1);   
    var m = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/models");
    updateTabs();
    m.application.observe(m.EVENT.ARGUMENTSCHANGED, updateTabs);
    function updateTabs() 
    {   
        console.log(m.application.arguments);
        var args = m.application.arguments;
        $('.section').hide();
        if (args[1] == "spotify") $("#playlist").html("args:"+args).show();
        else $("#"+args[0]).show();
    }
});
</script>

<div id="playlist" class="section">Container for playlist content</div> 
<div id="start" class="section">Welcome</div>  
<div id="playlists" class="section"> 
My <a href="spotify:app:tabtest:playlists:spotify:user:_username_:playlist_uri1">playlist1</a>
My <a href="spotify:app:tabtest:playlists:spotify:user:_username_:playlist_uri2">playlist2</a>
</div>
```

Thanks alot for all replys!

Comment: Using localstorage to store current location  ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Localstorage hmm, I don't have any ideas howto use that to update the url on second click. Do you have any suggestions? :)

Comment: I propose a solution using JQuery syntax.

Comment: I think you're refering to cache a playlist. I'd like to get rid of the cached url after clicking a playlist. 
I've recorded a mp4 to display the "error". My problem is: I haveto click the "Playlists"-tab twice to get back to the list. Videourl: http://87.237.208.91/files/spotify/

Comment: Humm, it seems I misunderstood...

Comment: Thanks anyway :) No other ideas after watching the screencap?

Comment: Force the location.href in the tab management ?

Comment: Would be awesome but I dont think I can do that. Or is there a way to access the spotify tab function from the app?

Comment: Why don't you force in the function updateTabs() using to see if you can do it : location.href="spotify:app:tabtest:playlists"; This is just for a try.

Comment: but then the playlist will never be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I will proceed using JQuery.

First of all you need to use the Localstorage :

```
var stor = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/storage");
```

Then if for exemple you get a list of playlist you can build the list like this

```
for (var i=0; i<d.playlists.length; i++) {
$('#playlists').append('My <a id="p' + i + '"href="'+ d.playlists[i] +'">playlist1</a>');
$('#playlists #p'+i).live('click', function(e) {
e.preventdefault();
stor.set('choosenplaylist', d.playlists[i]);
});
}
```

This was for the storage now for when changing tad :

```
if (!stor.get('choosenplaylist')=='') {
location.href=stor.get('choosenplaylist');
}
```

Okay this is a suggestion and it need to be tested regarding to your app.

Comment: Thanks alot, this solved everything! I thought this was a security violation but I guess not. :)

Answer (score 0):

Im trying this out now, and i can reproduce your bug (im guessing it's a bug, the tab *should* replace the url in my opinion)

But, until it's fixed, my best guess is to capture the playlist links in an event handler and cancelling the original event, after cancelling you replace the content with the appropriate playlist view.

[Tab test code (on gist.github.com)](https://gist.github.com/2875694)

I've abstracted the actual view binding from the event handler, and added a click event hook that calls the abstract view binder instead of the "real" one, this also supports deep linking into the an app

Comment: I realized that I've already tried this solution myself. It solves one problem and creates another. The back function stops working and the menu Playlists stops working after clicking a playlist. The Spotify Tunigo app seem to have been able to solve it.. How?

Comment: I think you should take a look at the navigation/history events, but i haven't tested this yet, i can take a look at it tomorrow.. this link might be of interest as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439145/reading-window-history-state-object-in-webkit

Comment: Ya maybe that could work. I assumed it was restricted looking at the Spotify Integration Guidelines: "Avoid history.pushState() for pushing new pages onto the stack - you’ll get a security exception if you try to do so." But I'll check it out..