# pushState & popState: Safari 5 not returning window.history.state

Tags: javascript, browser-history, pushstate, popstate

I can't seem to access the window.history.state object when my popState is triggered in Safari 5 (the page goes back). This code works perfectly in Chrome 19 and Firefox 12.

```
window.onload = function() {

     window.setTimeout(function() {

          var original = window.location.href;

          window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {

                    if (window.history.state !== null) {
                        var type = window.history.state.type;
                        var page = window.history.state.page;
                        //custom Ajax function below
                        getContent({type:type, page:page, category: category}, '/' + type + '/' + page);
                    } else {
                        window.location = original;
                    }

            }, false);

     }, 1);
}
```

console.log(window.history.state) in Safari 5 returns 'undefined'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439145/reading-window-history-state-object-in-webkit

This will be used to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`window.history.state` is only available in some browsers. It's not part of the spec per se.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Browser_compatibility)

```
Feature           │ Chrome  │ Firefox (Gecko)  │  IE  │ Opera  │ Safari
──────────────────┼─────────┼──────────────────┼──────┼────────┼───────
replace/pushState │   5     │    4.0 (2.0)     │  10  │ 11.50  │  5.0
history.state     │  18     │    4.0 (2.0)     │  10  │ 11.50  │  ---
```

Comment: this is not correct. it is 100% certainly also available in Chrome.

Comment: I just tested it in Chrome. It returns the proper Object.

Comment: @jeffhuber I guess your right, it was always available though

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=pushState It is available in every up-to-day browsers except IE9 and Andriod.

Comment: @Derek is it possible to get Safari to return out window.history.state. I get undefined.

Comment: @jeffhuber - I get `undefined` too. Looks like only Safari is partially supported.

Comment: @Derek take a look at the link my answer goes to

Comment: Seems Safari is the only browser.

Comment: ah - I read that page in my search. But I guess I missed that. Thanks. Good to have confirmation

Answer (score 2):

So if history.state is supported then the value will be null(or an object if the browser is remembering the state), otherwise it will be undefined. And I ended up with this code to check whether it's supported or not

```
(window.history && history.pushState && history.state !== undefined) 
? true : false;
```

Tested in latest Chrome, Safari 5, 6, IE 9

Comment: This used to work wonderfully, but [bug 949471](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=949471) stops it working in Firefox 26, and probably 27 too.