# jquery get url of forward page

Tags: jquery, browser-history, forward

How can I get the URL of a page from browser's forward history, but without actually redirecting there? I just want to save it as a variable, and then compare it with the current page.

Similar to `alert(window.location.pathname);` but from forward history.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439145/reading-window-history-state-object-in-webkit

Answer (score 0):

Getting the url for history isn't very easy due to privacy concerns. However, there are a few work arounds.

If you are trying to get the forward history on a page, and it's the last page you visited, you could try :

```
document.referrer
```

Otherwise, a cookie might be better suited for your needs :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.cookie("previousUrl", window.location.href, {path:"/"});
}
```